# Docusign API reminders/expirations

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm using Docusign's API to send reminders and expirations for a given envelope. I have seen that it is possible for Admins to disallow users by overwriting reminders and expirations defined in the DocuSign account.

The information about if is possible to "overwrite" or not is only available in an account endpoint and as a result the endpoint is available only for admin users.

As a non admin user how can I know if I can overwrite established reminders and expirations? So that I'm able to display to the user what he is capable to perform.

Docusign's own UI is able to block the user under the circumstances described above but I don't seem to understand which information they use for it.

Which is the correct API endpoint for the above use case?

Comment: which account endpoint you say is only available to admin?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/listsettings/ is this the one you tried?

Comment: Yes that endpoint was the only one that could retrieve such info but only admins could access it.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of that account-level setting, the API can always override the account's default reminders and expirations.

In other cases where the API can't override locked settings, making a GET call against the resource using the v2.1 API with `include_metadata=true` will add parameters that will tell you if a parameter is locked or not. More information on that is "Improved usability" section here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/new-v21/

As an example, you could create a draft envelope and do a GET call against it with `include_metadata=true` and `include=recipients` to tell if a particular recipient is locked for editing or not.

That said, the [account settings endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/listsettings/) Inbar listed is accessible for both users and admins. I called that endpoint as a non-admin member of my account and received this in the response:

```
        "userOverrideEnabled": "false",
        "reminders": {
            "reminderEnabled": "true",
            "reminderDelay": "44",
            "reminderFrequency": "33"
        },
        "expirations": {
            "expireEnabled": "true",
            "expireAfter": "22",
            "expireWarn": "11"
        }
    },
```